# Como transitar entre janelas?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou criando um sistema simples apenas para aprender um pouco sobre a biblioteca tkinter.
Porém, empaquei bem aqui.

A ideia é criar várias páginas no mesmo código (eu sei que o correto seria modularizar o código, mas por se tratar de um projeto pequeno, tudo junto irá servir). Porém, eu gostaria de poder apertar um botão e assim ficar viajando de uma página para outra.

Por exemplo, eu executo o programa e então me é mostrado a Página 1.

[image]

Ao clicar no botão "Página 2", eu deveria ir para a página 2. Onde lá deveria ter um botão "Voltar" que me leve de volta a Página 1.

[image]

E esse processo deveria ocorrer com qualquer página que eu queira criar.
Eu quero pedir essa ajuda, pois todos os códigos que eu encontrei eram muito confusos e/ou não trabalhavam com páginas isoladas separadamente onde o botão iria chamá-las.

Código:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

janela1 = Tk()
b1 = Button(janela1, text="Janela 2")
b1.grid()
b2 = Button(janela1, text="Janela 3")
b2.grid()
janela1.geometry("200x100")
janela1.mainloop()

sys.exit()

janela2 = Tk()
b3 = Button(janela2, text="Voltar")
b3.grid()
janela2.geometry("200x100")
janela2.mainloop()

janela3 = Tk()
b4 = Button(janela3, text="Voltar")
b4.grid()
janela3.geometry("200x100")
janela3.mainloop()
```

Comment: São "janelas" ou "páginas"?

Comment: Acho que não altera muito coisa.
Eu chamo de janela no código, mas página para o cliente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso existe o `Tkinter.Frame` e com o método `pack` para exibir o frame que deseja e usando o `pack_forget` (pode usar o `forget_grid` se for tabalhar com grids) para ocultar (remover), exemplo bem simples:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame2 = Frame(root)


def go_home():
    frame2.pack_forget()
    frame1.pack()


def go_second():
    frame1.pack_forget()
    frame2.pack()


root.title("páginas")

btn_page2 = Button(frame1, text="Página 2", command=go_second)
btn_page2.pack()

btn_home = Button(frame2, text="inicial", command=go_home)
btn_home.pack()

frame1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Também existe o método [**`raise`**](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/raise.html) que tem o equivalente em python como `frame.tkraise()`, que irá mudar a ordem dos frames adicionados no root, nesse caso ambos frames sempre estarão lá (nesse caso não achei documentado em Python, assim que encontrar vou tentar produzir um exemplo).

Comment: AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'pack_forget'

E é impressão minha, ou nesse teu código, tudo está numa página só, então tu vai ocultando e desocultando elementos?

Comment: Eu entendi o teu método e, apesar de não ser exatamente o que eu queria, creio que vai funcionar perfeitamente para o que eu quero.

Obrigado, Guilherme.

Comment: @IviFernando são frames diferentes, isso seria equivalente a páginas, agora se quer janelas diferentes, ai é outra coisa.

Comment: Eu notei isso. A sua solução fora perfeita pro meu caso.